# Multiline span behaves like a block?

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem styling two spans in a div. I need to make sure second span starts on the same line as the first one. I was able to make it work in Chrome:

[image]

But here is what I get in IE:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<div class="container">
  <span>7/2/2015</span>
  <span class="other">WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW</span>
</div>

.container {
    width: 200px;
}

.other {
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/alexarg/7q92t9m0/

Is there a way to make it work at least in IE 10? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Block functionality in Firefox as well.

Comment: Add display: block; on the `.other` class

Comment: You could try including `reset.css` (google it).  It removes many of the differences between browsers.

Comment: @Stanimir adding `display: block` to `.other` makes it wrap, but doesn't put it on the same line. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7q92t9m0/24/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a bug.  According to the [spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-text-3/#word-break-property):

> This property specifies soft wrap opportunities between letters, i.e.
>   where it is “normal” and permissible to break lines of text.

Soft wrapping of an inline element is based on the width of its block element ancestor.  Generally, that occurs where there's space or certain punctuation.  (Add an exclamation point or question mark randomly in the Ws, and it will break.)

The `word-break: line-break` [spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-text-3/#valdef-word-break-break-all) states that soft wrapping could occur between two letters, and that this property applies to "all elements."  However, it seems to work for block-level elements only in IE.

You can solve this particular problem by moving `word-break` to the container:

```
.container {
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2r7ozmkv/)

Comment: See my answer below for an explanation.

Comment: doesn't seem a bug IMHO, because Firefox was having the same behavior as IE. Chrome was the exception here ,

Comment: Opera works the same as Chrome, and the spec doesn't seem ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the differences between how browsers implement word wrap. Ironically, IE is doing the right thing in this case.

It would behave the same everywhere if the container was wide enough or if your second span had spaces in it.

If you want to suppress the word wrap, put both spans in a nowrap element together, but this will cause the spans to overflow their container when their container isn't wide enough.

Comment: Could you explain why IE is doing this correctly?  Since the span would wrap if it had spaces, I would think it should wrap using `word-break: break-all;`.

Comment: Break-all only works if the container has an absolute width set. And even then, some browsers will prefer to break on a space rather than between two letters.

Comment: According to the spec, this style applies to all elements.  You cannot set a width on inline elements, but they do have implicit widths, which allow soft wraps at spaces, and should therefore allow soft wraps between letters when using `break-all`.